# how to remove everything with rimraf except few exceptions

Tags: node.js, rm

i’m trying to remove all `.dot` files, except `.git` and all `*.js` except one `exception.js`, but i’m failing

### install

```
git clone git@github.com:iamstarkov/rimraf-test.git
cd rimraf-test
```

### test

```
npm test # it fails
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var globby = require('globby');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');

globby(['*', '!authors.js', '!.git', '!dump'])
  .then(function then(paths) {
    paths.map(function map(item) {
      rimraf.sync(item);
    });
  });
```